# XSD enumeration restriction not working

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

```
<xs:element name="featureTests">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="test" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="status">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="not run"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="passed"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="failed"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element> 
                        <xs:element name="summary" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="step" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I'm using the above XSD to validate my xml files which works fine all except for the `status` tag enumeration restriction.

if I do this:

```
<status>
    not run <!--OR passed OR failed-->
</status>
```

Validation fails saying that it must contain either [not run,passed,failed]

Could you tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes about because of the spaces/tabs in the xml doc surrounding the enumerated value ie having this "      not run       " instead of this "not run".

to solve this I changed the XSD file to use the token type rather than the string type to remove the leading and trailing whitespace characters:

```
<xs:restriction base="xs:token"> 
    <xs:enumeration value="not run"/> 
    <xs:enumeration value="passed"/> 
    <xs:enumeration value="failed"/> 
</xs:restriction>
```